JCE Cannot Authenticate Provider BC (bcprov-jdk18on-177.jar)
I have been using some library which has dependency on bcprov-jdk18on-177.jar. Using Oracle Jre I am facing Exception:JCE Cannot Authenticate Provider BC.
Although it is working fine with OpenJDK provided by Amazon Corretto

Add bouncycastle jar to JBoss classpath 2. Add 'org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider' to 'java.security' providers 3. Mark bouncycastle in your WAR as a 'provided' dependency. but still receiving same exception.


Are there any exception traces, if so could you post those if possible

If your bcprov jar is not validly signed, this is an expected difference between Oracle JDK and OpenJDK (link to 21, but this has been the same ever since OpenJDK started ~ Java 7). However the jars distributed from the BouncyCastle project are signed; did you get yours directly or via some other path?

@dave_thompson_085 Detailed exception :  file:/C:/Users/abc/Downloads/jboss-4.2.3.GA/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/lib/bcprov-jdk18on-1.77.jar is not signed by a trusted signer.

@Ironluca Have taken the library from Maven

It worked using latest available version of bouncy castle jar (bcprov-jdk15to18-1.78.1.jar) downloaded from https://www.bouncycastle.org/download/

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
